# My mac mini is not getting the FullHD Resolution for my FULLHD LED

Tags: mac-mini

I am having a LED with 1920*1080 resolution .I have connected my Mac mini using the Mini DisplayPort to VGA cable .I am only getting the 1280*1080 p.Why i am not getting FULLHD display

Comment: Why are you using a VGA cable instead of DisplayPort/HDMI?

Comment: currently have this ;Is it not work with VGA,as i know it has to display fullhd

Answer (score -2):

Try using the alt/option button while you change the settings for your display; i could upgrade to 1600/900; still no max resolution though cause i also have a full HD display